# Remove all js and css from theme [Drupal 7]

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In html.tpl.php I have 2 variables: $styles and $scripts

But they not reset by template function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
   $vars['styles'] = null;
   $vars['scripts'] = null;
}
```

How can I reset this variables?

Answer (score 1):

This game a jQuery not found error

```
drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_js');
```

I managed to remove all js by:

```
function TEMPLATE_js_alter(&$js){
    unset($js['misc/jquery.once.js']);
    unset($js['misc/jquery.js']);
    unset($js['misc/drupal.js']);
    unset($js['settings']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    # Reset CSS and JS
    drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_css');
    drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_js');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all data set to those 2 variables, you could use the *template_process_html()* hook which is called after the *template_preprocess_html()*.

```php
function MYTHEME_process_html(&$vars)
{
    $vars['styles'] = null;
    $vars['scripts'] = null;
}
```